# Stellar.js background not scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to use the Stellar.js script to apply a parallax effect.

Here is the official example from Mark Dalgleish's website
http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/demos/backgrounds.html

Even when I copy and paste the source code from the example, instead of having a slight scroll effect to each one image, they appear in fixed positions.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.
If even the Demo code does not work, check whether you gave the jquery or stellar.js path correctly.
You can check it in browser console, if you have any errors. The console will print it, if it can't load the resource.

2.
If the paths correct, check if you run the initialisation for stellar, when the page loaded, or if you gave "data-stellar-background-ratio" attribute for the right elements. If you give '0' to the data-stellar-background-ratio it won't scroll either.
Note that, it won't work on mobile devises either.

3.
If you checked everything above, and it still doesn't work, try to insert the scripts at the end of the  element. Sometimes it helps.
Something like this:

```
   <html>
    <head>
    <!-- Title, CSS, and other stuff -->
    </head>
    <body>
    <!-- Content here with right stellar attributes -- >
    ...

    <!-- At the end of body load the scripts, and run initialisation -->
       <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
       <script src="YOUR_PATH_TO_STELLAR/jquery.stellar.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

       <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).stellar({
        scrollProperty: 'scroll',
        horizontalScrolling: false,
        positionProperty: 'position'
       });
       </script>

   </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a situation where my `stellar.js` parallax scrolling wouldn't initialize until my browser window was resized. I found the `$.stellar('refresh');` seemed to fix the issue. (Using AngularJS)

```
angular.module('ForeverLeather').controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $(window).stellar({
    horizontalScrolling: false,
    verticalOffset: 0,
    horizontalOffset: 0,
    responsive: true,
  }).stellar('refresh');

}]);
```